# c90, POSIX, and clock_gettime

Tags: c

Before you read the question just know that this is "for the customer" therefore I have zero choice in the matter.

So our customer is using the c90 standard for their projects.  Up until this point we'd been using c99 and been happy to do it.  The function that is getting in our way from completing this task is `clock_gettime`.  We need a way to get millisecond accurate time for use in timing.

I'd looked at the c90 implementation of time.h and found that `time(time_t*)` is only accurate at the seconds level.  `clock` is supposed to let me know how many clicks have passed since the program started running but that is coming back erratic.  A `printf` I have in a 10000 repetition while loop is coming back with a `clock()` value anywhere from 30 to 120.  This is far too erratic to use.

So, the question is, does anybody know of a good c90 compliant way to get millisecond accurate system time?  We only are interested in the delta of two readings.

Thanks,
soulsabr

EDIT : As pointed out by zwol I forgot to mention I do know that `clock_gettime` is POSIX.  I think we're not too picky with the result so long as gcc on cygwin using `-std=c90` doesn't complain at us.  :)  In my defense I've been googling this all day and my brain hurts.

EDIT 2 : After further research I suspect I may be asking the wrong question due to me not understanding exactly what POSIX is and when it was defined.  So, looking through the `.h` for `time.h` I noticed that `_POSIX_TIMERS` is not defined when using `-std=90` which is why I can't use `clock_gettime`.  Defining `_POSIX_TIMERS` makes everything work.  So, I guess the question I should be asking is what is the proper way to "turn the missing POSIX functions on" or do you think simply defining `_POSIX_TIMERS` is an appropriate solution?

Also, if anybody thinks that I should nuke this question and ask it anew let me know and I will.

Comment: `clock_gettime` is not in C99 either, only in POSIX. (It *is*, iirc, in C11.) On that basis, you could perhaps go back to your customer and argue for use of POSIX functionality where C90 provides no way to accomplish your goal.  However, if you need to use C90 and nothing else, then you're hosed.  C90 simply does not provide the thing you need.

Comment: And I guess, you have a reason to not being able to use `gettimeofday()`?

Comment: @zwol if it is possible to use POSIX in gcc with the -std=c90 flag set I'm all for it.  As far as I've been told it just has to compile and run accurately with that flag under cygwin.

Comment: @SergeyA Absolutely no reason.  Looking it up right now.

Comment: @soulsabr I'm not deeply familiar with cygwin, but the first thing I'd try is `-std=c90 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`.  Some OSes (e.g. Solaris) insist on `-std=c99` if you want to use X/Open level 7, but I doubt Cygwin is one of them.  If that doesn't work, read through cygwin's headers; there is almost certainly *something* you can use in a `-D` switch to get `clock_gettime` declared.

Comment: (add'l:) You're technically not supposed to define `_POSIX_TIMERS` yourself, it's supposed to be something that `time.h` defines and you *check*.  There is probably an internal header that `time.h` includes, that conditionally defines `_POSIX_TIMERS` based on stuff like the value of `__STDC__`.  If this were Linux I would tell you to read `features.h` but I don't know if cygwin uses the same name.

Answer (score 3):

Two other functions to try, if `clock_gettime` is not available, are `ftime` and `gettimeofday`.  (`ftime` is really old, but it does give you subseconds).

As you may know, whether or not your compiler accepts these functions does not necessarily depend on the compiler language setting (C90 or c99 or c11).  It mostly depends on which header files you include and which functions your C library and OS support.

For `clock_gettime` you should include `<time.h>`.
For `gettimeofday` you should include `<sys/time.h>`.
For `ftime` you should include `<sys/timeb.h>`.

---

Addendum: as @nos points out in a comment, sometimes you do have to #define some symbol to enable these OS-specific, non-C functions.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Many systems (and I suspect cygwin as well) will only expose C90/C99 etc. functions from e.g. time.h if you only enable C90 or C99, and not expose the Posix extensions. You can `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`  before including such a header to enable the posix extensions.